# Kernel Convolution in Python 2.7

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, image

The code I wrote performs a mean blur on an image (I hardcoded it as zebra.jpg for testing purposes).
My problem is that for an image of 39KB image it take minutes to perform, is there any way of making this code more efficient?
Preferably using built in python modules.
Also is there any way of improving my code in other ways?

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('zebra.jpg')

img_w = img.size[0]
img_h = img.size[1]

# The bigger the kernel size, the more intense the blur
kernel = [[1]*10]*10

outputIm = Image.new("RGB", (img_w, img_h))
d = []
for y in range(0, int(img_h)):
    for x in range(0, int(img_w)):
        r, g, b, count = 0, 0, 0, 0
        index_y = int((len(kernel[0]) - 1) / 2.0) * -1

        for kernel_offset_y in kernel:
            index_x = int((len(kernel_offset_y) - 1) / 2.0) * -1

            for kernel_val in kernel_offset_y:

                if img_w > x + index_x+1 > 0 and img_h > y + index_y+1 > 0:
                    temp_r, temp_g, temp_b = img.getpixel((int(x + index_x), int(y + index_y)))
                    r += temp_r * kernel_val
                    g += temp_g * kernel_val
                    b += temp_b * kernel_val
                    count += 1
                    index_x += 1
            index_y += 1

        if (r > 0):
            r = r / count
        if (g > 0):
            g = g / count
        if (b > 0):
            b = b / count

        d.append((r,g,b))

outputIm.putdata([tuple(pixel) for pixel in d])
outputIm.save('blurred.jpg')
```

Comment: Try using pypy as well, as it is very good at speeding up this sort of code.

Comment: Usually FFT is an answer (definitely better than a brute-forsish approach you took). I am not sure it is an ultimate answer for your particular filter.

Comment: How would I go about implementing FFT here? @vnp

Comment: As usual, FFT the signal, FFT the kernel, (matrix-)multiply the results, and FFT back.

Comment: Do you have a link to where I can read more on FFT on images? Because I don't really understand what you mean @vnp

Answer (score 4):

#### Unnecessary type conversions

There are a couple of unnecessary type conversions, for example:

> ```
> index_y = int((len(kernel[0]) - 1) / 2.0) * -1
> ```

Casting to `int` truncates, but so does integer division.
So you can simplify the above with:

```
index_y = -(len(kernel_offset_y) - 1) // 2
```

In Python 2 integer division truncates by default,
so `... / 2` would work too.
But not in Python 3, where the behavior was changed.
Using `//` works in Python 2.7 and Python 3 consistently.

I also replaced the `* -1` with a simpler `-` prefix.

---

On this line, `x`, `index_x`, `y` and `index_y` are all integers,
so no need to convert them to `int`:

> ```
> temp_r, temp_g, temp_b = img.getpixel((int(x + index_x), int(y + index_y)))
> ```

---

This is also unnecessary:

> ```
> outputIm.putdata([tuple(pixel) for pixel in d])
> ```

Since `d` is already a list of tuples, you could write simply:

```
outputIm.putdata(d)
```

#### Simplify

The default start value of `range` is 0, so instead of `range(0, k)` you could write `range(k)`.

Instead of `x = x / y` you could write `x /= y`.

The parentheses are unnecessary in `if (expr):`.

#### Formatting

Instead of this:

> ```
> kernel = [[1]*10]*10
> ```

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends this writing style:

```
kernel = [[1] * 10] * 10
```

Comment: Awesome input, but is there any way to make the 4 nested for loops any more efficient?

Comment: @mark There is. Use linear algebra libraries like numpy. Unless you're doing this for learning purposes - use opencv or numpy http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html

Comment: I did this for learning purpose so using opencv isn't really my goal, but do you have any input on how I would implement a version with numpy?@user1685095